# Laravel 5.2, carry over article ID to next page and insert into database field

Tags: laravel

I am trying to use Laravel 5.2 to add questions to an article. Currently I can edit the article, using the edit function in the ArticleController. I want to have a button on the Article edit view, that allows the user to add a question. So when this is clicked, I need it to take the user to /articles/questions/create, but it needs to bring the ID for the article it has just come from with it, so it can be automatically stored in the article_id field in the db table. How would I do this, currently I can store the article ID by manually typing the in a text box on the creation form. Obviously, the aim is for the user to not have to know the ID of the article, and for it to be added automatically.

My Create function so far:
     public function create(){

```
$questions = Question::all();
$users = User::all();

$articles = DB::table('article')->where('id', 'article_id')->get();

return view('articles/questions/create', ['question' => $questions], ['users' => $users], ['article' => $articles]);

}
```

The form so far:

```
<h1>Create &amp; Add Question</h1>

{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'QuestionController@store', 'id' => 'createquestion')) !!}
{{ Form::hidden(csrf_token()) }}

<div class="row col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
    {!! Form::label('article_id', 'Article ID:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('article_id', null, ['class' => 'large-8 columns']) !!}
</div>

<div class="row col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
    {!! Form::label('title', 'Question:') !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('title', null, ['class' => 'large-8 columns']) !!}
</div>

<div class="row col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
    {!! Form::label('require', 'Required?') !!}
    {{ Form::radio('require', 1) }} Yes <br>
    {{ Form::radio('require', 0) }} No
</div>

<br>

<div class="row large-4 columns">
    {!! Form::submit('Add Question', ['class' => 'button']) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The form does successfully post the the Database, I just need the ID to automatically insert so that the article can reference it to show the question on the article page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all edit the below lines

```
$articles = DB::table('article')->where('id', 'article_id')->get();
return view('articles/questions/create', ['question' => $questions], ['users' => $users], ['article' => $articles]);
```

to

```
$articles = DB::table('article')->where('id', 'article_id')->first();
return view('articles/questions/create', ['question' => $questions, 'users' => $users, 'article' => $articles]);
```

Now, take a hidden field in the form you posted above

```
{!! Form::hidden('article_id', $article->id) !!}
```

and finally access the article id in your store method.

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $article_id = $request->article_id
}
```